# Create 3*3 and repeat it

Tags: angularjs

I want data to be shown in 3*3 matrix but single row only it showing.

This is my code

I have taken some dummy data which I want to repeat in HTML

Please provide some solution to  it.

```js
angular.module('App',[]);
angular.module('App').controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.groups = [{
        "id":1,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    },{
        "id":2,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    },{
        "id":3,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    }];
});
```

```html
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <th>Member</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
                
             
                <td ng-repeat="member in group">{{member}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to repeat through group.members in inner cycle ng-repeat="member in group.members"

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
  ng-repeat="member in group"
```

To

```
 ng-repeat="member in group.members"
```

You have problem however on the table header, you define table with 3 columns while in `members` some object only contain 2 data which may result row with 2 column.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple 3*3 matrix and rendered it in html.
You can take it as a reference.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Welcome varun';

  $scope.matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
    {{title}}
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in matrix">
      <td ng-repeat="data in row">
        {{data}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a working sample base on your code

```js
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.groups = [{
        "id":1,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    },{
        "id":2,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    },{
        "id":3,
        "members":[
            ["1","48","","","44"],
            ["1","48","","","44"]
        ]
    }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">   </script>
<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Member</th>
                <th>Age1</th>
                <th>Age2</th>
                <th>Age3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
                
                <td>ID: {{group.id}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="member in group.members">                [<span ng-repeat="X in member">{{X}}, </span>],</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```